# sort a data frame manually using non numeric column

Tags: r

i have the following data frame

```
    dd <- data.frame(b = c("High", "Medium", "Highest", "Low", "Not bad","Good", "V. Good"),
   x = c("C3", "C1", "C4", "N2", "C2", "N1","N4"), x = c("5", "2", "3", "6", "7", "5","7") )
```

so i want the data frame to be transformed using a manual order for the variable X.

for example: that's the original one

```
1    High C3   5
2  Medium C1   2
3 Highest C4   3
4     Low N2   6
5 Not bad C2   7
6    Good N1   5
7 V. Good N4   7
```

but what i want is a new data frame to begin based on the value of X but not alphabetically, but randomly in an order which i chose e.g:

```
the first row has x=C1, the second have x=C2, the third have x=N4, ...etc
```

how this can be done??

thank you

Comment: Does your data.frame really only have 7 rows? If so, why not just create it in the correct order in the first place? Alternatively, to reorder, use `dd[c(2, 5, 7, etc), ]`, where 2, 5, 7, and so on, are the row numbers in the order that you desire.

Comment: @jbaums: no it's not, but that's a part of it and all the the rest is the same part for the X Variable but the other variable are different. so i want to apply this for all the data frame based on their X value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the `x` column is a factor, 
you can simply ensure that its levels are in the order you want.

```
# New sorting order
desired_order <- sample(levels(dd$x))
# Re-order the levels
dd$x <- factor( as.character(dd$x), levels=desired_order )
# Re-order the data.frame
dd <- dd[order(dd$x),]
```

Comment: i did not get how i can assign the order i want??

Comment: You should specify the desired order in the `desired_order` variable
(without duplicates). In the example, I just used a random order, but you can specify it by hand, e.g., 
`desired_order <- c("C1", "C2", "N4", "C4", "N1", "N2", "C3")`.

Comment: but this will work for the whole data frame(including sub-data frames of the same type)??

Comment: Yes, this will work for the whole data.frame. I am not sure what you mean by "sub-data.frame".

Comment: ok, it worked now. thank you. but there is still one small problem, the data frame is ordered as i want but when i plot it the ordering changes, why?? and how can i fix this??

Comment: For someone who might struggle with this as I am, you just need df$column <- factor(as.character(df$column), levels=c("first", "second", "third")), then you sort and assign it back to the original dataframe using df <- df[order(df$column),]

Answer (score 1):

If your `data.frame` really is small enough to manually reorder, then just make a vector of the numbers `1:7`, ordered in the way that the rows should appear. e.g.:

```
    dd[c(2,5,7,1,4,3,6),]

    b  x x.1
    2  Medium C1   2
    5 Not bad C2   7
    7 V. Good N4   7
    1    High C3   5
    4     Low N2   6
    3 Highest C4   3
    6    Good N1   5
```

Or, if you really want to do it with a character vector, you can also reference by row names, like this:

```
    rownames(dd) <- as.character(dd$x)
    dd[c("C1","C2","N4","C3","N2","C4","N1"),]

    b  x x.1
    C1  Medium C1   2
    C2 Not bad C2   7
    N4 V. Good N4   7
    C3    High C3   5
    N2     Low N2   6
    C4 Highest C4   3
    N1    Good N1   5
```

Comment: it's not that small,  but that's a part of it and all the the rest is the same part for the X Variable but the other variable are different values. so i want to apply this for all the data frame based on their X value(but also i would consider each one as a small data frame and apply this ordering to it)