# How to order rows according to two conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, multiple-conditions

Given data:

```
df

Var1   Var2   Values
aaa     x        4
aaa     y        7
aaa     z        6
bbb     x        9
bbb     y        21
bbb     z        13
ccc     x        4
ccc     y        19
ccc     z        0
```

Goal: Order the rows according to Var1 and Var2

First step: ordering rows according to Var1

```
df %>% dplyr::arrange(match(Var1, c("bbb", "ccc", "aaa")))
```

```
Var1   Var2   Values
ccc     x        4
ccc     y        19
ccc     z        0
bbb     x        9
bbb     y        21
bbb     z        13
aaa     x        4
aaa     y        7
aaa     z        6
```

Second step:
How to order Var2 while keeping the order of Var1?
How to get the following output?

```
Var1   Var2   Values
ccc     z        0
ccc     y        19
ccc     x        4
bbb     z        13
bbb     y        21
bbb     x        9
aaa     z        6
aaa     y        7
aaa     x        4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort (order) data frame rows by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/sort-order-data-frame-rows-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arrange` and `desc`

```
df %>% 
    arrange(desc(Var1), desc(Var2))

  Var1 Var2 Values
1  ccc    z      0
2  ccc    y     19
3  ccc    x      4
4  bbb    z     13
5  bbb    y     21
6  bbb    x      9
7  aaa    z      6
8  aaa    y      7
9  aaa    x      4
```

Comment: Thank you very much... What if the order is not necessarily alphabetical. But for example 
Var1: bbb, ccc, aaa and Var2: yyy, xxx, zzz?

Comment: Then you should use a factor variable and order the levels as desired. You can take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391910/sort-a-data-frame-manually-using-non-numeric-column).

Comment: Great, thank you!